# What is code golf?

Tags: support

I only find this description, which is partly recursive: "Code Golf - Stack Exchange is for programming puzzles and code golf". Maybe for native english speakers it is perfectly obvious, but I didn't find a translation for 'code golf'.

Is it the attempt to find the shortest solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should our FAQ look like?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-should-our-faq-look-like). In particular, see [What is a code golf?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-should-our-faq-look-like/3#3)

Comment: Fine. And why doesn't the FAQ look like that?

Comment: This site is still in beta and the issues of what should be in the FAQ are still in discussion and development.

Comment: Isn't gnibblers explanation obviously better than what is now written in the faq? I would suggest to put it in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the game of golf, you win by minimising the number of strokes to complete the game.

In code-golf, each character is equivalent to a stroke in golf, so you win by using the smallest number of bytes.

You may even see people using the words "bytes", "characters", and "strokes" interchangeably here.